# ActiveMq message converter not working with JmsTemplate

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I am using spring JmsTemplate and AMQ as message broker. Following is the piece of code that I have done. I create Jmstemplate and then set MessageCoverter. But when I am doing this then system throw an error.

```
private JmsTemplate createJmsTemplate(final MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
    jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
    jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
    jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean(name = "messageConverter")
@Lazy
public CorrelationIdAwareMappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter() {
    CorrelationIdAwareMappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new CorrelationIdAwareMappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setTypeIdPropertyName("__type");
    return messageConverter;
}

@Component
public class JmsTestSubscriber {

        private TestService testService;

        @Autowired
        public JmsTestSubscriber(final TestService testService) {
            this.testService = testService;
        }

        @JmsListener(destination = "test.queue", containerFactory = "jmsTestFactory")
        public boolean receiveMessage(final EntityEvent entityEvent) {
            log.info(entityEvent.toString());
            return true;
        }

    }

    cannot convert
```

from [[B] to [com.test.dto.TestEvent].

Now if I remove message converter then its working fine. 
could someone help me on this.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace. Are you expecting the message body to be a byte[]? The error message is indicating the message body is a byte array. "[B" is Java default .toString() for byte[].

Comment: No, I am expecting message as Json, as you can in first method I set this converter with JmsTemplate and in second method initialized type of converter. I am unable to understand after setting converter why published not using this converter and instead send data in byte.

Comment: You'd need to share the source code of the message converter

Comment: I added the JMS Subscriber code where messages are being received.

Comment: source for CorrelationIdAwareMappingJackson2MessageConverter?